# Why do vectors exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Vectors are basically described by two quantities and have some magnitude and direction.

Why did the people who invented vectors invent it?What is the use of bundling numbers into groups of two?Why do vectors exist?

Comment: Two quantiles, magnitude and direction are only a model of vector in two-dimensional real space.

Mathematician will say: "Vector is nothing else but element of vector space". Mathematics does not say what is a number, what is a vector, what is a set. In geometry we dont define what is a line, what is a point. We treat them as given, and only give rules to them.

Mathematics models reality, not recreates reaity.

Comment: What is vector space?

Comment: A set of vectors, with 2 operations - You can add vectors and multiply vectors by elements of a chosen field.

Comment: Exist: Because we want them to. // Why: Because it was useful. // What: Analytical geometry in the case of Descartes, complex numbers and extensions as numbers and algebraic structures (like relations of determinants) in the case of Euler, Gauß, Hamilton and Grassmann.